# Describe transit gateway peering attachment

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am getting following errors while describe the transit gateway peering attachments more than one and not getting the error while describe the transit gateway peering attachments with single peering attachment.

**Code**

```
data "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_attachment" "example" {
  
  filter {
     name    = "state"
     values  = ["pendingAcceptance","available"]
  }

  filter {
     name   = "transit-gateway-id"
     values = ["<Transit_gateway_id>"]
  }
}
```

**Error**

> Error: multiple EC2 Transit Gateway Attachments matched; use additional constraints to reduce matches to a single EC2 Transit Gateway Attachment
> │
> │   with data.aws_ec2_transit_gateway_attachment.example,
> │   on main.tf line 5, in data "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_attachment" "example":
> │    5: data "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_attachment" "example" {

Comment: Are you using only one TGW ID in the second filter?

Comment: Yes I have used the only one TGW ID.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, as error tells, you have multiple attachments matching filter. You should make filter more precise. If you create tgw attachment in terraform just [add it's id to filter](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/ec2_transit_gateway_peering_attachment#by-filter). If you are looking only for pending attachments remove "available" from state's values.

Comment: I like to get both available and pendingAcceptance state of the TGW peering attachment ids. It is giving the results if we have single TGW peering attachment state is either of available and pendingAcceptance. It is not giving the results  if we have multiple  TGW peering attachment state is either of available and pendingAcceptance

Comment: @Jai that is a problem.  aws_ec2_transit_gateway_attachment data block does not expect get multiple objects. It is designed to represent only one peering attachment. From what I see there is no "plural" data block for peering attachments (like [aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment) and [aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachments](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachments)).

Comment: Yes correct. Terraform doesn't give "plural" data block for peering attachments